# VBA code for copying value from a range into another range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a piece of VBA code that perform's the following:

1. Return the cell reference of a cell using the value in cell G13 to determine the column:

   =ADDRESS(2,MATCH(G13,A2:K2,0),4)
2. Copy the value in range CDPayment into that cell.

The code I have written thus far is:

```
Dim populate As Long

populate = "=ADDRESS(2,MATCH(RC[-3],R[-11]C[-9]:R[-11]C[1],0),4)"
'This will be the variable that holds the cell reference of the cell I want to copy the       values to

Range("CDPayment").Copy
Sheets("Rec").Range("populate").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I am new to VBA so any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems like you are requesting a software development rather than asking the question: could you please narrow down your post to a clearly-defined question? Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Can I recommend an alternative approach?  Give cell G13 an alias name just like you did with the "CDPayment" range.  If CDPayment is a list of numeric values, assign it with the sum value using Range.(MyAliasName) and the sum function:

```
Sheets("Rec").Range("MyCell").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("CDPayment"))
```

If it's just a single string value:

```
Sheets("Rec").Range("MyCell").Value = Range("CDPayment")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have decided to go a different way.             'code' Dim y As Integer


    On Error Resume Next
    
    y = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("G14"), Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 11)), 0)
    
    ActiveSheet.Cells(10, y).Value = Range("CDPayment")
    
    
    If x = "" Then
        MsgBox "No matching value found"
    End If


End Sub'